# Cannot create Set from String array

Tags: java

I've been staring at the screen the last 5 minutes and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong:

```
class Example {

    private final Set<String> values;

    public Example(String... values) {
        values = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(values));
    }
}
```

I'm surprised why the `String[]` cannot be converted to `List<String>` to initialize the `HashSet<String>` with it.

I'm getting the build error:

> ```
> incompatible types: java.util.HashSet<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.lang.String[]
> ```

What's wrong with my assignment?

Comment: The `values` parameter inside of your constructor is shadowing the class field `values`.

Comment: As @ajp15243 said.  You can fix it by assigning to `this.values`, or by changing the name of the constructor argument.

Comment: @AbhijeetKushe that make a nice answer

Comment: Correct answers were already given so I thought I will make a comment

Comment: @AbhijeetKushe You're making a good point which I would definitely upvote, but it's up to you

Comment: Convert into an answer

Comment: Why does this question have so many upvotes? It's a simple mistake and not a very interesting question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing a qualification to actually access the private field. Currently you're trying to reassign the parameter passed to the constructor. Instead you should use the following code:

```
public Example(String... values) {
     this.values = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(values));
}
```

This can be shortened even further by using the "Diamond Operator", which is avaliable since Java 7:

```
public Example(String... values) {
     this.values = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(values));
}
```

Comment: Facepalm... Thanks Vogel!

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can do it

```
 if(values != null)
      this.values = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(values));
 else
      this.values = Collections.emptySet();
```

Add the if(values != null) check before the assignment.Whenever you use var args you are exposing a contract which will permit your clients to create an valid Example object without any arguments.If you want to avoid that from happening then just use String[] values directly and throw an exception incase if it is null

Comment: You're right that I should validate my inputs, excellent point. Actually I think throwing `IllegalArgumentException` might be best for a `null` arg.

Comment: Yeah IllegalArgumentException would be ideal if use Sting[] values as the parameter

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have addressed the cause, but wouldn't it be better to simply rename the parameter to avoid the shadowing?

Comment: Good point. I wouldn't have been in this situation in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.values inside a constructor in place of value because the parameter of constructor is string array and you are trying to convert a List  to array.

this.values = ......

Comment: I don't understand how you ended at the correct result with such a wretched premise... Your logic is... abysmal

Comment: @Vogel612 perhaps the formulation of this answer is a bit confusing, but the conclusion seems to be totally correct.